# Search a Sharepoint List using html form web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list and a html form (dropdown list) that filters the SharePoint list. Because of the list view threshold causing degradation in performance as the list gets large I want to avoid filtering and just use the search bar in the Sharepoint list. The list view threshold doesn't affect the search function. So with that said I want to use the same html form webpart values and append them to the search bar using javascript instead of establishing a connection to the list and filter it. Here is my form as it currently is.

```
    <div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<select name="T1">
<option></option>
<option value="Administrative Record">Administrative Record</option>
<option value="Bankruptcy">Bankruptcy</option>
<option value="CBI">CBI</option>
<option value="Continuing Violations">Continuing Violations</option>
<option value="D’Aubert – Expert Witness">D’Aubert – Expert Witness</option>
<option value="Discovery">Discovery</option>
<option value="Due Process">Due Process</option>
<option value="Financial Assurance">Financial Assurance</option>
<option value="Final Agency Action">Final Agency Action</option>
<option value="FOIA">FOIA</option>
<option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
<option value="Misc">Misc</option>
<option value="Mitigation Projects">Mitigation Projects</option>
<option value="Next Generation Compliance">Next Generation Compliance</option>
<option value="Penalty">Penalty</option>
<option value="Statute of Limitations (SOL)">Statute of Limitations (SOL)</option>
<option value="Supplemental Environmental Projects (SEPs)">Supplemental Environmental Projects (SEPs)</option>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Apply Filter" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/></div>
```

How can I send the values of this form to the search bar in my SharePoint list using Javascript

Comment: Have you considered using the dedicated Search web parts instead?

Comment: The search web part doesn't allow me to search a specific list. The workarounds are too much for me right now. I am working on taking the form values and placing them in the list search box. I will post if I have a solution.